# Sorting Excel Columns

Tags: excel, excel-2016

Suppose the excel sheet has 2 columns :

```
A 1

B 3

C 1

C 2

A 6

B 5

A 5
```

I want to sort the columns in such a way that the entry in the other row corresponding to that entry stays with it. So the sorted data would be :

```
A 1

A 6 

A 5

B 3

B 5

C 1

C 2
```

Basically I want to group data.

Comment: I just want to sort based on the first column. But I also want the entries corresponding to the columns to stay with it.

Answer (score 1):

Select those two columns.

Now go to `Data` > `Sort` and as a `Sort by` select 1st column.

That will do it.